# Will adding a single edge to a given graph create a new shortest path?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding

Assume I have a directed graph with a start node A and an end node C, and I already know that the shortest path from A to C in this graph is of length `n` and uses nodes A, B<sub>0</sub>,B<sub>1</sub>, ..., B<sub>n-2</sub>, C.

I want to know whether adding a given new edge to this graph will create a new shortest path from A to C of length `< n`. Of course, I could simply use Dijkstra's algorithm to check the shortest path in this new graph, but my question is whether the information we have about the shortest path in the graph *without* this new edge can somehow be used to solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: Do you have only this path? Or do you have the output of dijkstra's algorithm without the new edge? (for each `v` you have `d(v)` as the distance from `A`)?

Comment: That would depend on the graph, and can't be determined easily. For example, if the new edge is `A-C`, then it obviously would create a new shortest path. However, if it's `X-Y`, where neither `X` nor `Y` have a path leading to `C` from them, then it just as obviously can't possibly affect the shortest path. There might be some heuristics you could use if either `X` or `Y` are already part of the shortest path, but even if they're not, the possibility of a new shortest path is there...

Answer (score 3):

You add a new edge `(u,v)`, you need to check if the triangular inequality holds:

```
d(v) < d(u) + w(u,v)
```

If it does, there is no new shortest path.

Otherwise, you have a new shortest path from the source (`A`) to `v`, which invalidates all shortest paths with weight greater than the new `d(v)`.